# Segmentation fault by using MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather

Tags: c++, mpi

I was trying to calculate elementwise multiplication of matrix elements.
But I've got this error and don't know what to do.

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 16855 RUNNING AT kevlinsky-PC
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

The task was to split it between processes, calculate the result and return it to the zero process.
Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    const int n = 4;

    int arrayA[n][n];
    int arrayB[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++) {
            arrayA[i][j] = (rand() % 1000) - 500;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++) {
            arrayB[i][j] = (rand() % 1000) - 500;
        }
    }

    int getbufA[n];
    int getbufB[n];

    int arrayC[n][n];
    int bufC[n];

    MPI_Scatter(&arrayA, n, MPI_INT, &getbufA, n, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(&arrayB, n, MPI_INT, &getbufB, n, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bufC[i] = getbufA[i] * getbufB[i];
    }

    MPI_Gather(&bufC, n, MPI_INT, &arrayC, n, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("MATRIX C \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                printf("%d ", arrayC[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Could you explain what you did to build and run this code?

Comment: I’m using this one: https://www.mpich.org/downloads/
To compile:
    *mpic++ -o main.out main.cpp*
To run:
    *mpirun -np ‘number of the threads’ ‘absolute path to the main.out file’*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your error:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; i++) {
    arrayA[i][j] = (rand() % 1000) - 500;
}
```

You need `j++` in this loop. And you have this error in two places. `j` is never incremented and stays `0`, and `i` is incremented indefinitely (because the condition for the loop is based on `j`), so very soon you go out of bounds for the array, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: Such a trifle... Thanks a lot!